# Error by loading subcaption using the LNCS class

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, subfloats

I've used the subcaption package without any problem.
Now I am drawing the tikz picture using the documentclass [LNCS](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines).

If I use the subcaption package,

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Fig1} \label{fig1:a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
        \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Fig2} \label{fig1:b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fig1} \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

If I use the subfig package,

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig2:a}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }\
\subfloat[]{\label{fig2:b}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
        \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\caption{Fig2} \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I also get the same error.
However, if I use the documentclass article, both cases compile fine.

Any idea on what the problem might be? (Using the subcaption package may be better if possible.)

Comment: Both example works fine to me.  Tested with recent MiKTeX.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, when I compile them on the overleaf, there is a warning.

Comment: This may be a case, since Overleaf hasn't installed recent version of packages. It will renewed with TeXlive 2022 (I'm not its user). However, warning is not error and so it should not harm your document compilation.

Comment: The message you've encountered is a warning message, *not* an error message.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this? I am not sure whether the editor will have trouble compiling my codes. :(

Comment: Not really. Of all the warning messages that the `caption` package can produce, this has got to be one of the mildest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes that want to print captions in a special way are usually not compatible with the `caption` package, which is only able to interact with a few classes (the standard ones, the KoMa ones and possibly a few others).

If you load `caption` with an unsupported class, you'll get at least a warning and `caption` would hijack the captions as defined by the class, which is *not* wanted, because such classes are usually meant for submissions to journals (articles) or publishers (books) and the work would be likely rejected for noncompliance with the required typesetting format.

Of course, loading `subcaption` is likewise forbidden with such classes.

Can you have subfloats, then? Yes, you can use `subfig`, provided you load it *without* `caption`.

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\subfloat[]{\label{fig2:a}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\quad
\subfloat[]{\label{fig2:b}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
        \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\caption{Fig2} \label{fig2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Beware of spurious spaces (check the `%` characters I added).

[image]